# regex to find an if or while statement in source code

Tags: java, regex

I am attempting to create a regex that will be able to identify if and while statements in a String representation of some source code. I am then going to use the regex to invert the boolean condition associated with this statement by inserting "!(" and ")" where appropriate using the String.replace() function in Java.

The regex should be able to identify the if and while statements regardless of the use of statement blocks or how many parts the condition has or how "nested" the condition is.

In other words, all of the following statements should be recognized by the regex:

```
if(true)
function();

if(true){
    function();
}

if((true && thing.isEmpty() || i > 2){
   function();
}

if((true && thing.isEmpty() 
   || i > 2){
function();
}
```

(and so on, to include equivalent while statements as well)

I was able to come up with a regex that appears to work for ifs and whiles where statement blocks are used:

```
"(if|while)[\\s]*[\\(]([^\\{])*\\{"
```

Unfortunately, the problem with this is that if the code I am processing has an if or while that doesn't use blocks, that the ([^\\{])* portion of the regex will suck up everything until it finds the next \\}.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
private static int negateBool(File inFile, File outFile, int numMuts){

    // establish character counter
    int charCounter = -1;

    try{
        // set up the output
        if(!outFile.exists()){
            outFile.createNewFile();
        }
        PrintWriter fileOut = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(outFile.getPath()));

        // convert input file into a string
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inFile);
        String content = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
        scanner.close();

        String regex = "(if|while)[\\s]*([^\\{]*)\\{";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);

        int intCounter  = numMuts;


        while(matcher.find() && intCounter > -1){ // if a potential mutation has been found
            System.out.println("ping");
            if(intCounter > 0){ // if this mutation has been done already
                intCounter--;
            }
            else{ // a new mutation has been found, intCounter == 0
                charCounter = matcher.start(1);

                // do the mutation
                fileOut.write(content.substring(0,matcher.start(1)));
                String part = content.substring(matcher.start(1),  matcher.end(0));
                part = part.replaceFirst(regex, "$1(!$2){");
                fileOut.write(part);
                fileOut.write(content.substring(matcher.end(0), content.length()));

                intCounter = -1;
            }
        }

        fileOut.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return charCounter;
}
```

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1171 is fairly spot on here - by trying to use regular expressions, a fast string matching language, for doing something it can't do, namely grammar parsing, you've just made things impossibly hard for yourself. Write a token-reader instead that tracks whether it sees an if/while construction and you can add in the start/end detection for the conditional body.

Comment: Your question as it stands sounds very contrived. What is the intended use case for this code?

Comment: This problem is impossible to solve with 1 regex, and even 2 or more would be complicated, and even then, there will be cases that will break it (like strings or comments in conditional arguments).  Furthermore, your use of regexes indicates to me that you have only a very tenuous grasp on regexes to start with (for example, it's not necessary to use character groups for everything: there's no need to say `[\s]*`; you can just say `\s*`).  I agree with Lambda Fairy; you're trying to do something very complicated in a contrived manner.